# Issue in laravel database query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to run query which will fetch data between the given dates but i am not getting a desired result. I have an blank array as an output.

**this is my code in controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use \Carbon\Carbon;

class reportController extends Controller
{
    public $response;

public function contact_report(Request $request){
    if($request->header('content-type')=='application/json'){
        $from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->from)->format('Y-m-d');
        $to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->to)->format('Y-m-d');
        $cont_report = DB::connection('mysql_freesubs')->table('contact as c')
                        ->select("c.fname", "c.lname","c.dob", "cl.value","c.doc" )             
                        ->join("communication_link AS cl", "c.id", "=", "cl.cont_id")
                        ->join("contact_communication AS cc", "cl.coco_id", "=", "cc.id")
                        ->where("cc.type", "like","mobile%")
                        ->whereBetween("c.doc", [new Carbon($from), new Carbon($to)])
                        ->get();
        $response = $cont_report;

    }
    else
        $response =  response()->json(['data'=>[],'error'=>1,'success'=>0,'error_msg'=>'not application/json', 'message'=>'Content type should be application/json']);

    return $response;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class reportController extends Controller
{
    public $response;

    public function contact_report(Request $request){
        if(0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')){

            $from = Carbon::parse($request->from)->format('Y-m-d');
            $to   = Carbon::parse($request->to)->format('Y-m-d');
            $cont_report = DB::connection('mysql_freesubs')->table('contact as c')
                            ->select("c.fname", "c.lname","c.dob", "cl.value","c.doc" )             
                            ->join("communication_link AS cl", "c.id", "=", "cl.cont_id")
                            ->join("contact_communication AS cc", "cl.coco_id", "=", "cc.id")
                            ->where("cc.type", "like","mobile%")
                            ->whereBetween("c.doc", [$from, $to])
                            ->get();

            //$this->response = $cont_report;
            return response()->json(['response' => $cont_report], 200);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json([
                'data'=> [],
                'error'=> 1,
                'success'=> 0,
                'error_msg'=>'not application/json', 
                'message'=>'Content type should be application/json'
            ], 404);        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried returning `$response` from within the if statement, like so?

```
class reportController extends Controller
{
    public $response;

    public function contact_report(Request $request){
        if($request->header('content-type')=='application/json'){
            $from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->from)->format('Y-m-d');
            $to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->to)->format('Y-m-d');
            $cont_report = DB::connection('mysql_freesubs')->table('contact as c')
                    ->select("c.fname", "c.lname","c.dob", "cl.value","c.doc" )             
                    ->join("communication_link AS cl", "c.id", "=", "cl.cont_id")
                    ->join("contact_communication AS cc", "cl.coco_id", "=", "cc.id")
                    ->where("cc.type", "like","mobile%")
                    ->whereBetween("c.doc", [new Carbon($from), new Carbon($to)])
                    ->get();
    $response = $cont_report;
    return $response;

}
else
    $response =  response()->json(['data'=>[],'error'=>1,'success'=>0,'error_msg'=>'not application/json', 'message'=>'Content type should be application/json']);
    return $response;

}
}
```